# Eloquent ORM, how to avoid redundant queries?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Suppose I have the field status in all my database tables. When I want to delete a record, instead of purging it I set the value of field status to 0. This means of course all my queries will always use a where clause such as:

```
WHERE status = 1
```

However, this means I have to write and append where('status', '=', 1) to all methods of my eloquent model. It will always be like:

```
Post::find(1).where('status', '=', 1)
Post::where('status', '=', 1)->get()
Post::find(1).where('status', '=', 1).comments().where('status', '=', 1)->get()
```

Is there a way to define something as a default scope to have where status = 1 always present in all methods of my model and all the time?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Take a look here: [http://usman.it/filter-eloquent-results-overriding-laravel/](http://usman.it/filter-eloquent-results-overriding-laravel/) Using this example you would have to apply it to every model, but you could make a new base model class that had this code in it and then let all your models extend that one instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, at least regarding soft delete:

http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scope methods.

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    $query->where('status', '=', 1);
}
```

Then, you use like this:

```
Post::active()->get();
```

Comment: Then you have to use active() in all methods, and in some cases you would have to use it more than once, such as Post::find(1)->active()->comments->active(). As you see it doesn't help.